# How can I deconstruct this line into multiple lines in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React component:

```
const AuthInit: FC<WithChildren> = ({children}) => {
  const {auth, logout, setCurrentUser} = useAuth()
  const didRequest = useRef(false)
  const [showSplashScreen, setShowSplashScreen] = useState(true)
  // We should request user by authToken (IN OUR EXAMPLE IT'S API_TOKEN) before rendering the application
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestUser = async (apiToken: string) => {
      try {
        if (!didRequest.current) {
          const {data} = await getUserByToken(apiToken)
          if (data) {
            setCurrentUser(data)
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        if (!didRequest.current) {
          logout()
        }
      } finally {
        setShowSplashScreen(false)
      }

      return () => (didRequest.current = true)
    }

    if (auth && auth.api_token) {
      requestUser(auth.api_token)
    } else {
      logout()
      setShowSplashScreen(false)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])

  return showSplashScreen ? <LayoutSplashScreen /> : <>{children}</>
}
```

The component contains this line of code:

```
return () => (didRequest.current = true)
```

How can I deconstruct this line into multiple lines so that I can put a breakpoint on `didRequest.current = true`?

Comment: To give an arrow function a multiline body use curly brackets instead of parens. `return () => {`, new line, `didRequest.current = true;`, new line, `}`

Comment: Thanks. I converted it into three lines:

      return () => {
        didRequest.current = true;
      }

but I can only get the debugger to break on the first line (return). It doesn't want to break on the second line, didRequest.current = true;, for some reason. I click on "step into" and it jumps over the second line and continues to the third line which is the end curly brace. Any ideas?

Comment: (sorry, deleted my previous comment). What's the purpose of the function? If it's a cleanup function for the effect, you'll need to move it outside of requestUser. Or if it's doing something else, you'll need to call it at some point. Right now you just return it from requestUser, but then never do anything with it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out :D That's why I wanted to put a breakpoint to be able to tell if that line is being hit or not.

Comment: It's not running because you are not executing the anon function, you are just returning it.

Comment: So when will it get hit? Never? The didRequest const exists in literally just these four places in the entire codebase.

Comment: I mean it is used here: if (!didRequest.current) {
          const {data} = await getUserByToken(apiToken) and here: if (!didRequest.current) {
          logout() and the default value is false so it seems didRequest will never be able to be truthy? If that's the case, what's the point of both of these lines: if (!didRequest.current) {

Comment: React will call your cleanup function each time before the Effect runs again, and one final time when the component unmounts (gets removed).

Comment: There is no cleanup function. That's the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateDidRequest = () => {
  didRequest.current = true;
}
return updateDidRequest;
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put the function?

Comment: inside useEffect

Comment: Tried. Still not hitting the breakpoint.

Comment: That entire return statement seems redundant. I've still no idea how the didRequest variable is supposed to work or what it's for.